# FileStream and ObjectDisposedException in .NET CF

Tags: c#, compact-framework, filestream, objectdisposedexception

```
public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream aStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(aStream);
    binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] binFile = binReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(binReader.BaseStream.Length));
    binReader.Close();
    return binFile;
}
```

I run this method for a number of filepaths, problem is whenever a file cannot be accessed with File.Open (because it is used by another process) I get:

```
'aStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
```

on the following line:

```
binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
```

And seldom I get

```
{System.IO.IOException: The process can not access the file '\folder\file.txt' because it is being used by another process.}
```

This is the exception I want. So why is the object disposed most of the times?
Note: I first had the FileStream line in a using statement but removed it because I thought that might have disposed the object. But the problem remains.

Edit: Using Compact Framework, which doesn't have `ReadAllBytes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe** that part of the time your `FileStream` is throwing the `IOException` whenever your file is in use, and at other times, **perhaps**, you are getting the `ObjectDisposedException` because your array is not initialized.

Obviously, I can not test this theory.

See if you can copy-n-paste this one with good results:

```
public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
{
  byte[] binFile = null;
  try
  {
    using (var aStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(aStream);
      binFile = new byte[binReader.BaseStream.Length];
      binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0; // <= this step should not be necessary
      binFile = binReader.ReadBytes(binReader.BaseStream.Length);
      binReader.Close();
    }
  } catch (IOException err) {
    // file is being used by another process.
  } catch (ObjectDisposedException err) {
    // I am guessing you would never see this because your binFile is not disposed
  }
  return binFile;
}
```

Be sure to check for null return variables!

**EDIT:**

I wrote (what I think is) a simpler version. I tested it, and it seems to work OK. I also prefer `Read()` overload to `ReadBytes()`, because I know how much data was pulled in.

First, is the test function that calls the method for every image in my Pictures folder:

```
public void Test() {
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
  foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories()) {
    if (-1 < subDir.Name.ToLower().IndexOf("pictures")) {
      foreach (var file in subDir.GetFiles()) {
        byte[] data = GetFile(file.FullName);
        if (data != null) {
          Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public byte[] GetFile(string filename) {
  byte[] result = null;
  try {
    if (File.Exists(filename)) {
      int len = 0;
      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
      byte[] data = new byte[file.Length];
      using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))) {
        len = br.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        br.Close();
      }
      if (0 < len) {
        if (len == data.Length) {
          return data;
        } else {
          // this section of code was never triggered in my tests;
          // however, it is good to keep it as a backup.
          byte[] dat2 = new byte[len];
          Array.Copy(data, dat2, len);
          return dat2;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException err) {
    // file is being used by another process.
  } catch (ObjectDisposedException err) {
    // I am guessing you would never see this because your binFile is not disposed
  }
  return result;
}
```

I don't see any reason why these would not work - unless you are having an `int` overflow.

Comment: copy-pasted it but still got the same result...this line causes it:                     binFile = new byte[binReader.BaseStream.Length];

Comment: How large is this file you are trying to read? The only minor glitch I see in the code is that `BaseStream.Length` is a `long` that would need to convert over to an `int`. Is your file too large?

Comment: "Is your file too large?" - Yes I think it is! I think the problem is gone after I converted it to an int. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use

```
public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
{
    try { return File.ReadAllBytes(filename); }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Just for fun, you could even define an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static byte[] GetFile(this string filename)
    {
        try { return File.ReadAllBytes(filename); }
        catch { return null; }
    }
}
```

so you could do `byte[] myfile = filename.GetFile();`.
Remember you **must** check that return is not null before proceed:

```
if (myfile != null)
{
    // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: Why create a GetFile method at all?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: well, just to manage the exception if file is in use.. it's the only reason I see here...

Comment: @Marco Forgot to mention Im using Compact Framework so I cant use ReadAllBytes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention Im using Compact Framework so I cant use ReadAllBytes.